# Piping a dockerfile string to `docker build` from Node.js is not working

Tags: node.js, docker, child-process

I am trying to pipe a Dockerfile to `docker build` via stdin as mentioned here:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specify-a-dockerfile--f

I have tried everything, and Docker just doesn't seem to accept the my stdin.

```
const dockerfileStr = 'FROM alpine-node'
const child = spawn('docker build . -f -', {shell:true, stdio: ['pipe', 'inherit']})
child.stdin.write(dockerfileStr + '\n')
child.stdin.end()
```

Maybe it expects a `tty`?

The PR that added this request is here: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/31236/files

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was just being slow because my build context was massive. And it didn't seem to report status...